# Transpose from Consumer to CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future, consumer

I'm currently using an API which I unfortunately cannot change easily. This API has some methods in the style of this:

```java
public void getOffers(Consumer<List<Offer>> offersConsumer) {
        final Call<List<Offer>> offers = auctionService.getOffers();
        handleGetOffers(offersConsumer, offers);
    }
```

It's a web api using retrofit, and it enables me to process the response in a consumer, but I much rather want to work with CompletableFutures.

I'm using the data I receive from this endpoint to compose an interface in a game, and therefore compose an inventory, that basically acts as a frontend to the api. What I want to do, is to have my composing method to wait for the consumer to finish, and then provide the processed results. This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to do the step from the consumer to the CompletableFuture:

```java
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Inventory> get(Player player) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            auctionAPI.getOffers(offers -> {
                //process the offers, then return the result of the processing, in form of an "Inventory"-Object.
                }

            });


        });
    }
```

I now need to return the result of the processing after all the Items have been received and then processed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Make a `CompletableFuture` with the constructor, and implement the `Consumer` with `future::complete`.

Comment: you need to simplify this code, otherwise this is not answerable. Like "convert to an ItemStack" - we have no idea what that is. So, how about a simpler example?

Comment: @Eugene I tried to remove some of the unneccessary information to make my case more clear, I hope that's more in the style

Comment: you could do `CompletableFuture<Inventory> result = new CompletableFuture<>(); CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { auctionAPI.getOffers(offers -> { .... result.complete(your_inventory) ... ; return result;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines should work:

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<Inventory> get(Player player) {
    CompletableFuture<Inventory> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        auctionAPI.getOffers(offers -> {
            //process the offers, then return the result of the processing, in form of an "Inventory"-Object.
            result.complete(inventory);
            }

        });
        return null;
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I changed the supplyAsync to runAsync, but still worked

Comment: @monamona yes, using `runAsync` eliminates the need to `return null;`. It would also be a good improvement to encompass the code of the runnable with `try … catch(Throwable t) { result.completeExceptionally(t); }` to ensure that the future won’t stay uncompleted in the erroneous case. That’s one of the rare cases where `catch(Throwable …)` is justified.